# Is it possible to move an MQ message from one queue to another?

Tags: jms, message-queue, ibm-mq

I need to move one single message from an MQ queue to another queue. This other queue may already have existing messages in it. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!  You can do this at the command-line using the Q program which is supplied as [SupportPac MA01](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24000647&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en) or if you would like a GUI you can use [SupportPac MO71](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24000142&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en) instead.